# Trying to create a contact us form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

The goal of this code is to have someone fill it out then it sends their typed message to my email. I've looked online for some references, and being so new to php I'm having a lot of trouble understanding why when I click the send button it shows my php pages code. My question is why am I not getting an email when pressing the send button on the contact form?

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">

<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Type</p>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Question</option>
<option value="change">Information Change</option>
<option value="addition">Information Addition</option>
<option value="new">Misc.</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>

<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "dnasim09@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-     decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: Why is the code posting my php code instead of sending me an email message?

Comment: Is your php code on the same page as form?

Comment: Do you have installed and running any local server, for example XAMPP https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html ?

Comment: I think that, the best way to make contact form with users, is storing those messages in a database.

Comment: I have XAMPP, and the php is on a separate page called mail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your code doesn't check for errors.
- You have php in same page and    didn't mention what is the name of
  form file (means your action is doubtful.)

Set you `action=""` so that the form is sent to the page itself. Execute Php code only if form is being posted, for that i added a `name` to you submit button and in Php checked if submit exists in `%_POST` array telling Php when to execute this code. Since you'll be at the same page so i changed text of anchor tag.

**Note: This code assumes that is being executed on server where email server is configured and no error occurs during execution**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">

<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Type</p>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Question</option>
<option value="change">Information Change</option>
<option value="addition">Information Addition</option>
<option value="new">Misc.</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="sendemail" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["sendemail"]))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "dnasim09@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-     decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Go Somewhere you are already home ;)</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify. My php is on a separate php page called mail.php

Answer (score 0):

You also have a very common error a lot of people have with "Contact Us" forms.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
```

This will break SPF and also cause DMARC to fail and you will never get the message from some people, if your mail server you use has DMARC enabled on it and GMAIL does.

Since DMARC is a more recent protocol, a lot of the old cookie cutter code for contact us forms - doesn't take this into account.

You can read more about that here: ["DMARC - Contact Us Form Nightmare"](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)

The suggested workaround will be to do:

```
$email = "dnasim09@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form Email: " . $_POST['email'];
```

This way - you avoid the issue outline in the article. You won't quickly be able to hit the "Reply" button, but at least you'll get the emails from those customers who have DMARC enabled.